# Multiple figures on the last page

Tags: floats

I am using the following template. The figures appear at the end of the document and each figure has a new page. I want figures at the end of the document but not only one figure per page.

```
\documentclass[Journal,letterpaper]{ascelike-new}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[figurename=Fig.,labelfont=bf,labelsep=period]{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath}
\usepackage[colorlinks=true,citecolor=red,linkcolor=black]{hyperref}

\usepackage[version=4]{mhchem}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{longtable,tabularx}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\setlength\LTleft{0pt} 
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{stfloats}


\begin{document}

\title{Title}

\section{First section}

sample text

\begin{figure}
\centering
\framebox[3.00in]{\rule[0in]{0in}{1.00in}}
\caption{An example figure-1 (just a box).}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
\centering
\framebox[3.00in]{\rule[0in]{0in}{1.00in}}
\caption{An example figure-2 (just a box).}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Thanks

Comment: `! LaTeX Error: File 'ascelike-new.cls' not found.` please give a link to that class (which presumably defines `figure`)

Comment: Thank you for your reply.
Please find the file here:
https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/template-for-preparing-your-submission-to-the-american-society-of-civil-engineers-asce/pbwcqsvndpty#.V18ZYflVhBd

Comment: The class sets up endnotes to do this, it is presumably a requirement of their production process, It offers an `InsideFigs` option to not use endfloats.

Comment: Just to add to @DavidCarlisle's comment, `InsideFigs` places floats in text. As you _want figures at the end of the document_, you will have to manually place all floats at the end.

Comment: You could create a new float class and use endfloat to only use that class (nofigures, notables).

Comment: Thank you for your comments.
I am not able to use InsideFigs. I will be grateful if you can provide a sample syntax.

Regards